# Successfull Forgeries

Tags: history, jewish-books

Which forgeries have successfully fooled significant sectors of Jews before being revealed as forgeries. I.e. works falsely attributed to someone besides the real author.

I can think of the Besamim Rosh, Auerbach Eshkol (which few still dispute is a forgery), and the Friedlander Yerushalmi on Kodashim. Are there any others?

Comment: What do you mean by forgery. Falsifying the name of the writer, or writing/popularizing false information?

Comment: @user6591 I meant the former. what would be an example of the latter?

Comment: eldad hadani comes to mind. Things like that.

Comment: Well the yerushalmi was also the latter, no? Or maybe he was just melaket different things

Comment: @user6591 Eldad hadani attributed his book of shchita to Yehoshua, didnt he?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @mevaqesh i'm no expert, but i think he attributed all his laws back to Moshe and Yehoshua, but I don't think he came with a book in his hand. Stuff was subsequently written. But I don't know. Another thing I don't know is how or why people vote on this site. It gets to me sometimes. It seems people vote with their hearts, not their minds, which is unfortunate in this type of setting.

Comment: The maharal and the golem

Comment: @DoubleAA wasnt that a story-book; it was inauthentic inasmuch as it was a lie, but it wasnt a forgery as it didnt claim to be authored by Maharal, or anyone besides the author if memory serves.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't specify that the author had to intentionally mislead.

Comment: @mevaqesh the letter of the Maharal that was forged to support it, complete with Maharal's signature, was certainly meant to mislead.

Comment: Does this question include forgeries that were so successful, that even now significant sectors of Jews believe their authenticity?

Answer (score 3):

The Haggadah of the Maharal, to the extent that it is not just collecting comments of the Maharal from elsewhere, was a forgery, and was generally accepted as being from the Maharal.  I heard that the Radzhyner Haggada to this day cites the Maharal Haggada as a source that one must drink the *kos shel Elyahu* as a fifth cup, despite that the Maharal himself in Gevuros Hashem writes that one may drink a fifth cup if he wants to and does not relate it to the *kos shel Elyahu*.

Comment: Where can I find more info on this?

Comment: @user6591 Shnayer Leiman has some stuff about it.  Moriah had an article about it once.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/2408 @user6591

Comment: @Yez this single discrepancy is evidence enough to label the entire work a forgery?

Comment: @user6591 no.  That single discrepancy was my evidence of how widely it was accepted as being from the Maharal.  It was "published" by a known forger, there are anachronistic references, and there is no valid account of how it came to be "discovered" 350 years later and where it was in the meantime.

Comment: @Yez if you have a chance to post a link or two I'd appreciate it. I tried searching leiman's piece you mentioned,but didnt get anywhere.

Comment: @yEz If it was widely accepted, it must be authentic, even with seemingly anachronistic references and exceedingly late discovery with no good back-story. To think otherwise is to essentially question the entire Jewish Mesorah.